# Trigonometry and algebra question

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Given:

- The total length of `ad + dc`
- The lengths of each `ab`, `bc` and `ca`
- That `angle adb` = `angle cdb`

How can I work out lengths `ad` and `cd`

[image: diagram]

Comment: @Willie, you migrated a question that's already over here!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: me? I didn't vote to migrate at MO (check the voters list there!) In any case, instead of complaining, just vote as duplicate. This way all the links will be automatically updated in a proper way.

Comment: @Willie, sorry. Anyway, I flagged it. I didn't think I could vote to close as duplicate; I thought a question had to have an answer to do that, and neither version had an answer yet.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Grr... I keep forgetting about that silly requirement about closing as duplicates (as you can see moderators are not bound by it). Thanks for the flag.